# Unconventional models and Peano Arithmetic

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]^+ \models \mathsf{PA}^-$. What are the initial segments of this model?

Comment: Who are "they"? You should indicate where you encountered the problem. The second sentence seems like a somewhat random list of things, but does not show that you have engaged with the question beyond noting the terms in it. That gives the appearance that you found the question somewhere else, rather than having come up with it yourself.

Comment: We welcome questions that you have encountered elsewhere, but you should indicate where you found the question and what you have actually tried, rather than just copying the question as you have done in several instances.

Comment: I removed the "computability" tag, which is unrelated to this question, and added the "peano-axioms" tag

Comment: @CarlMummert, I added some thought about the question

Comment: You have not added very much. Which textbook, exactly? Which problem is it, on which page? Are you familiar with the notation, such as $\vDash$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x^+$. It may be that you are trying to read too fast and need to start with a general introduction to logic before trying to solve problems that take a background in logic for granted. This is the sort of problem that is usually intended to be completely straightforward.

Comment: @Carl, this is from Enderton but not sure no the page. Can you help with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

To show that a certain model satisfies $PA^{-}$, make a list of all the axioms of $PA^{-}$ (they are the 15 axioms listed on [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations)). Then check, one at a time, that $\mathbb{Z}[x]^+$ satisfies each of these axioms.